# How to deploy ONLY Cloud Functions without affecting Hosting?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

Basically, I'd like to: `firebase deploy --only functions` **without remove my  webapp*** (Hosting). Every deploy takes too long because of this step: `hosting: preparing . directory for upload...`, so I'd like to skip it without affecting my previously deployed webapp.

How could I do that?

***I deleted by mistake my webapp (which is in production) by using this: `firebase deploy --only functions`**

Comment: If you can replicate, [file a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The --only functions flag should not delete your hosted files.  If that happened, I suspect you discovered a bug. I'd try confirming that you can delete your app with the --only functions flag and submit a support request to the Firebase team.

Comment: Let me replicate the issue. If it happens again, I will report it. But when I was deploying my app using ```--only```, Functions were deployed and everything else was removed. But as a Firebase lover, I will suppose that something was wrong with my config.

Comment: It wans't a bug, it was my fault—shame on me. Thanks for your help!